# How can I spy on element?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Let's say I have this directive:

```
.directive 'panelcreator', ->
    (scope, element)->
        element.bind 'mouseenter', ->
            element.addClass 'alert alert-danger'
```

To keep this a  unit spec, I want to stub out `element.addClass`, right? So how do I go about doing this?

My attempt:

```
describe 'panelcreator', ->

    describe 'something', ->
        beforeEach ->
            spyOn(element, 'addClass')
            element.trigger('mouseenter')

        it 'shoud create a panel', ->
            expect(element.addClass).toHaveBeenCalledWith 'alert alert-danger'
```

Gives me:

```
Error: Expected a spy, but got Function.
```

How do I go about analysing a variable such as `element` in future so I can find out the method chain I need to pass `SpyOn`?

Answer (score 2):

If using jQuery, `addClass` will be on the jQuery object:

```
spyOn($.fn, 'addClass');
```

If not, it will be on jqLite (angular.element) object:

```
spyOn(angular.element, 'addClass');
```

Comment: Darn, thought that would do it but neither work. `Expected spy addClass to have been called with [ 'alert alert-danger' ] but actual calls were [ 'ng-scope' ]` Would I be right in thinking that's nothing to do with my directive, it's just angular doing its thing?

Comment: @Starkers yes, angular uses addClass to add `ng-scope` classes. I think you have an issue with the timing of when you attach the spy, as your directive seems to be doing something else here that creates a new scope. You can change when you attach the spy, inspect the spy's calls with `angular.element.addClass.calls` and try to find the call that adds your specific classes, or just test the existence of the class itself on the element. There isn't much value in stubbing something as ubiquitous as an add class method.

Comment: I know what you're saying about addclass being ubiquitous but I'm just trying to teach myself javascript TDD so I'm being a bit OCD I know. I'll play around with .calls tomorrow....also I've started a bounty with a condition you might be interested in...

Comment: Stubbing the global `jqLite` functions is a bad idea, as it might break some unrelated functionality. Tests should work with real `Element`s inside the wrapper, not try to mangle the wrapper. @Starkers : Teaching yourself TDD also means learning when **not** to use a particular pattern, in this case stubbing (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to stub `addClass` to *"keep it a unit spec"*, there's nothing wrong with using a real `Element`.

Stubbing a method is good when testing use of some discrete interface with a single point of access.  DOM elements, however, are complex data structures with (usually) more than one way to perform a certain action. **If you were to test that your function adds an element to an `Array`, you wouldn't want to stub `.push()` either** (as there are many other ways to add an item). So, when testing DOM interaction, you can just add DOM elements to the list of "utility" stuff you're allowed to use (instead of stubbing).

When testing whether a class is added, just check its presence.

---

*Note that this makes your bounty question invalid. To make it absolutely clear in general terms:*

Yes, you *could* inspect the source code of `jqLite` (possibly by stepping through `addClass` call) and find out that you need to observe the real `Element`, not its `angular.element()` wrapper. Thus, you could try to stub [`Element.classList.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).

However, the whole previous paragraph is irrelevant. Stubbing is only appropriate when you need to test use of an entity without the need to provide an implementation and/or rely on it. Both `Element` and its `jqLite` wrapper have guaranteed forward-compatible stable functionality and their implementation is implicitly provided, since your code runs in a web browser and uses AngularJS. This makes stubbing either of them counter-productive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

`spyOn(element.prototype, 'addClass')` ?

and then

`expect(element.prototype.addClass).toHaveBeenCalledWith 'alert alert-danger'`

Comment: I have no, but that gives me: `Error: spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for addClass()` which is odd..

Comment: @Starkers that's because the correct syntax is `element.__proto__` and _not_ element.prototype - of if you need it to work in old browsers `element.constructor.prototype`.

Comment: This answer is missing the point, which is that the two `element` variables in the question code contain two different instances of `angular.element()` wrapper (encapsulating the same `Element`).